# map() error using Angular 2 & Typescript

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 application, where I have implemented a pipe to basically check some null values. Problem is when I use `map()` I get the below error:

```
core.umd.js:2838 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in app/components/performances/performances.component.html:18:10 caused by: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Below you can take a look my code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Performance} from '../common/performance';

@Pipe({
    name: 'defaultPerformanceValueIfNull'
})

export class PerformanceCheckValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(values: Performance[]): any {
            let performances = values.map(function(p) {
                return Object.assign(p, 
                    { 
                        OneMonthBack: p.OneMonthBack || '-',
                        ThreeMonthsBack: p.ThreeMonthsBack || '-'
                    })
            });
            return performances;
        }
}
```

I think the code is ok, you can take a look an example I have write here: 
[link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20values%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%201%2C%20name%3A%20%22Test%201%22%2C%20OneMonthBack%3A%20null%2C%20ThreeMonthsBack%3A%20567%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%202%2C%20name%3A%20%22Test%202%22%2C%20OneMonthBack%3A%20234%2C%20ThreeMonthsBack%3A%20null%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%203%2C%20name%3A%20%22Test%203%22%2C%20OneMonthBack%3A%20657%2C%20ThreeMonthsBack%3A%2045%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%204%2C%20name%3A%20%22Test%204%22%2C%20OneMonthBack%3A%20null%2C%20ThreeMonthsBack%3A%20null%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20id%3A%205%2C%20name%3A%20%22Test%205%22%2C%20OneMonthBack%3A%2056757%2C%20ThreeMonthsBack%3A%20567%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20performances%20%3D%20values.map(function%20(p)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(p%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OneMonthBack%3A%20p.OneMonthBack%20%7C%7C%20'-'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ThreeMonthsBack%3A%20p.ThreeMonthsBack%20%7C%7C%20'-'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aperformances.forEach(console.log)%3B)

any idea what its going on with my code? 
thanks!

Comment: have you tried just importing the map operator. ie..... `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` or import all operators with `import 'rxjs/Rx';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this, to make your Pipe more bulletproof!

Seems like during your first pipe-transform that input-data is undefined!

```js
export class PerformanceCheckValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(values: Performance[]): any {
      if (!values || !values.length) return [];

      return values.map(p => Object.assign(p, { 
            OneMonthBack: p.OneMonthBack || '-',
            ThreeMonthsBack: p.ThreeMonthsBack || '-'
          })
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mxii it's working fine with the change you told me, but I don't understand why I have to do it. I'm using the pipe only in one place.. doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: It's cause of your data you want to `transform` is during the first change-detection `undefined`. Assume your variable is something like this `values:  number[];`. Its undefined and will be declared via http.get or something similar.. You could change it to `values: number[] = [];`.